# process.WaitForExit() is not waiting in Mac OS X - ASP.NET Core 2.2

Tags: macos, asp.net-core-2.2

I have an **ASP.NET Core 2.2** application. When I call the below Test Method (from Chrome browser), based on the OS Type, a new **Incognito** instance of Chrome browser will be opened.

In Windows and Linux (running in Virtual Box), the `process.WaitForExit()` is waiting till the **Incognito** Chrome Browser is closed.

But, in Mac OS X (running in Virtual Box), the `process.WaitForExit()` is not waiting. It's immediately called after `process.Start()`.

How to ensure the process is Waiting till the browser is closed?

```
public IActionResult Test()
    {
        string fileName = "";
        string arguments = "";

        if (RuntimeInformation.IsOSPlatform(OSPlatform.Windows))
        {
            fileName = @"C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe";
            arguments = @"-incognito --user-data-dir=""C:\Users\bala_sakthis\AppData\Local\Temp\ChromeData"" data:,";                
        }
        else if (RuntimeInformation.IsOSPlatform(OSPlatform.Linux))
        {
            fileName = "google-chrome";
            arguments = @"-incognito --user-data-dir=""/home/osboxes/ChromeData"" data:,";                
        }
        else if (RuntimeInformation.IsOSPlatform(OSPlatform.OSX))
        {
            fileName = "open";
            arguments = @"-a ""Google Chrome"" -n --args --incognito --user-data-dir=""/Users/bala/ChromeData"" data:,";
        }

        var process = new Process();
        process.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
        process.StartInfo.FileName = fileName;
        process.StartInfo.Arguments = arguments;

        using (process)
        {
            try
            {
                process.Start();

                process.WaitForExit();

                Console.WriteLine("Process exited...");
                Console.WriteLine(process.HasExited);
            }
            catch (Exception exp)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(exp);
            }
        }

        return new OkResult();
    }
```